# How to use boundary condition for Euler-Bernoulli equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

How to use enter boundary condition into a Euler-Bernoulli fourth order equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, first integrate step by step to obtain

$$\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
  {\frac{{{d^4}y}}{{d{x^4}}} = F} \\ 
  {\frac{{{d^3}y}}{{d{x^3}}} = Fx + A} \\ 
  {\frac{{{d^2}y}}{{d{x^2}}} = \frac{F}{2}{x^2} + Ax + B} \\ 
  {\frac{{dy}}{{dx}} = \frac{F}{6}{x^3} + \frac{A}{2}{x^2} + Bx + C} \\ 
  {y = \frac{F}{{24}}{x^4} + \frac{A}{6}{x^3} + \frac{B}{2}{x^2} + Cx + D} 
\end{array}$$

Next, apply your boundary conditions to obtain a linear algebraic system for the unknown constants $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$

$$\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
  {y(0) = 0}& \to &{D = 0} \\ 
  {y(l) = 0}& \to &{\frac{F}{{24}}{l^4} + \frac{A}{6}{l^3} + \frac{B}{2}{l^2} + Cl + D = 0} \\ 
  {\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}(0) = 0}& \to &{C = 0} \\ 
  {\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}(l) = 0}& \to &{\frac{F}{6}{l^3} + \frac{A}{2}{l^2} + Bl + C = 0} 
\end{array}$$

and hence

$$\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  \frac{A}{6}{l^3} + \frac{B}{2}{l^2} =  - \frac{F}{{24}}{l^4} \hfill \\
  \frac{A}{2}{l^2} + Bl =  - \frac{F}{6}{l^3} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.\,\,\,\, \to \,\,\,\,\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  \frac{l}{6}A + \frac{1}{2}B =  - \frac{{F{l^2}}}{{24}} \hfill \\
  \frac{l}{2}A + B =  - \frac{{F{l^2}}}{6} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$$

Solve for $A$ and $B$. I will leave obtaining the constants to you. :)

Comment: Thank you for this help it will go a long way. Sorry to be a pain but do you have any suggestions on the best way to obtain these constants?

Comment: @AdamMacmartin: I just obtained two of them, so you need to just solve for $A$ and $B$! :) I will add one more step to the question. :)

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. I was getting myself confused.